# integration-get a result of wrong type

Tags: r, integration

My formula is

```
 $$\int_{a}^{b}\big(exp(x) +1 \big)^{i\cdot u} \cdot \text{cos} \big((x-\alpha) u \big)dx$$
```

Here is my R code for integration:

```
 a<--2; b<-2; u<-0.15; alpha<-0.8

 integrand<-function(x)
{
 (exp(x)+1)^(1i*u)*cos((x-alpha)*u)
}

integrate(integrand,lower=a,upper = b)
```

After running this code, I got the error message from R:

```
Error in integrate(integrand, lower = a, upper = b) : 
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong type
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: what's `i` here?

Comment: @AK88 i denotes $$\sqrt{-1}$$

Comment: do you mean `sqrt(-1)`?

Comment: @AK88 yes, it is the square root of -1

Comment: you have to use other packages to do complex integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `integrate` cannot do complex integration. Use `elliptic` package's `myintegrate` instead:

```
 a<-2
 b<-2 
 u<-0.15
 alpha<-0.8

integrand<-function(x) {
   (exp(x)+1)^(1i * u)*cos((x-alpha)*u)
 }

 myintegrate(integrand,lower=a,upper = b)
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments!!

Comment: you are right! the function 'integrate()' cannot do complex integration. The package 'elliptic' works! I also tried another approach, and get the same result:  integrate(function(x){Re(integrand(x))},lower=a,upper = b)$value+1i*integrate(function(x){Im(integrand(x))},lower = a,upper = b)$value

Comment: I have seen the latter approach, but I was not sure about the math part. Do you think its correct for your case?

Comment: I am not sure if it is correct. I tested different data and these two approaches return the same results :)